# Open workbook then show / display

Tags: excel, vba, userform

I have written code to sort data into columns/rows.

I have a final sheet where this data is copied and pasted. Once this action is completed a userform to appears for user input.

When my macro opens the new workbook it only displays the userform. The workbook is not available for viewing although Excel says it is open.

The code I have so far is:

```
Sub Measurement_Info()
Dim iL As Long, rng1 As Range, _
  sizex As Long, sizexs As Long, i As Long, _
  Commentrng As Range, Commentpaste As Range, _
  ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet, ws3 As Worksheet, _
  x As Workbook, y As Workbook, _
  rng2 As Range, pasterng As Range, _
  lRow As Long, lRows As Long, _
  var As Range, var1 As Range, var2 As Range, var3 As Range, _
  var4 As Range, var5 As Range, var6 As Range, var7 As Range, _
  var8 As Range, var9 As Range, _
  titlerow As Long

Dim Title1 As Range, Title2 As Range, titlerows As Long, comments As Range, _
  MSG1 As Integer, app As New Excel.Application, stitle As String, objExcel

Set x = Workbooks.Open("C:\VBA Macros\Measurement Database Tool\INCALog\LogFileComments.csv")

Set ws1 = Workbooks("LogFileComments").Worksheets("LogFileComments")
Set ws2 = Workbooks("Measurement Database SPA").Worksheets("Measurement Info Sheet")
Set ws3 = Workbooks("Measurement Database SPA").Worksheets("Measurement Signal List - SPA")

'Text to columns, seperate into columns
ws1.Columns(2).TextToColumns , _
Destination:=ws1.Range("B1"), _
DataType:=xlDelimited, _
TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, _
ConsecutiveDelimiter:=True, _
Other:=True, _
OtherChar:="|", _
TrailingMinusNumbers:=False

iL = ws1.Cells(ws1.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
For i = 1 To iL
Set Title1 = ws1.Cells(i, 1)

titlerow = ws2.Cells(ws2.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
titlerows = titlerow + 1
Set Title2 = ws2.Cells(titlerows, 1)
Title2.Value = Title1.Value
Set rng1 = ws1.Range(ws1.Cells(i, 1), ws1.Cells(i, ws1.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Columns)
Set var = rng1.Find("Date: ", LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart)
If Not var Is Nothing Then
lRow = ws2.Cells(ws2.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
lRows = lRow + 1
Set pasterng = ws2.Cells(lRows, 2)
pasterng.Value = var.Value
End If

Set var1 = rng1.Find("Time: ", LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart)
If Not var1 Is Nothing Then
lRow = ws2.Cells(ws2.Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Row
lRows = lRow + 1
Set pasterng = ws2.Cells(lRows, 3)
pasterng.Value = var1.Value
End If

Set var2 = rng1.Find("Recording Duration: ", LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart)
If Not var2 Is Nothing Then
lRow = ws2.Cells(ws2.Rows.Count, 4).End(xlUp).Row
lRows = lRow + 1
Set pasterng = ws2.Cells(lRows, 4)
pasterng.Value = var2.Value
End If

Set var3 = rng1.Find("Database: ", LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart)
If Not var3 Is Nothing Then
lRow = ws2.Cells(ws2.Rows.Count, 5).End(xlUp).Row
lRows = lRow + 1
Set pasterng = ws2.Cells(lRows, 5)
pasterng.Value = var3.Value
End If

Set var4 = rng1.Find("Experiment: ", LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart)
If Not var4 Is Nothing Then
lRow = ws2.Cells(ws2.Rows.Count, 6).End(xlUp).Row
lRows = lRow + 1
Set pasterng = ws2.Cells(lRows, 6)
pasterng.Value = var4.Value
End If

Set var5 = rng1.Find("Workspace: ", LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart)
If Not var5 Is Nothing Then
lRow = ws2.Cells(ws2.Rows.Count, 7).End(xlUp).Row
lRows = lRow + 1
Set pasterng = ws2.Cells(lRows, 7)
pasterng.Value = var5.Value
End If

Set var6 = rng1.Find("Devices: ", LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart)
If Not var6 Is Nothing Then
lRow = ws2.Cells(ws2.Rows.Count, 8).End(xlUp).Row
lRows = lRow + 1
Set pasterng = ws2.Cells(lRows, 8)
pasterng.Value = var6.Value
End If

Set var7 = rng1.Find("Program Description: ", LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart)
If Not var7 Is Nothing Then
lRow = ws2.Cells(ws2.Rows.Count, 9).End(xlUp).Row
lRows = lRow + 1
Set pasterng = ws2.Cells(lRows, 9)
pasterng.Value = var7.Value
End If

Set var8 = rng1.Find("WP: ", LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart)
If Not var8 Is Nothing Then
lRow = ws2.Cells(ws2.Rows.Count, 10).End(xlUp).Row
lRows = lRow + 1
Set pasterng = ws2.Cells(lRows, 10)
pasterng.Value = var8.Value
End If

Set var9 = rng1.Find("RP: ", LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart)
If Not var9 Is Nothing Then
lRow = ws2.Cells(ws2.Rows.Count, 11).End(xlUp).Row
lRows = lRow + 1
Set pasterng = ws2.Cells(lRows, 11)
pasterng.Value = var9.Value
End If

Set comments = var9.Offset(0, 1)
Set Commentrng = ws1.Range(comments, ws1.Cells(i, ws1.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft))
sizex = Commentrng.Columns.Count
sizexs = sizex + 11
Set Commentpaste = ws2.Range(ws2.Cells(titlerows, 12), ws2.Cells(titlerows, sizexs))
Commentpaste.Value = Commentrng.Value

Next i

'Close x:
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
x.Close
Application.DisplayAlerts = True

'close & save Final sheet
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Workbooks("Measurement Database SPA").Save
Workbooks("Measurement Database SPA").Close
Application.DisplayAlerts = True


MSG1 = MsgBox("Would you like to add comments", vbYesNo, "Add comments")
If MSG1 = vbYes Then
Set y = Workbooks.Open("C:\VBA Macros\Measurement Database Tool\Measurement Database SPA.xlsm")
Set objExcel = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
objExcel.AppActivate "Microsoft Excel"
Set objExcel = Nothing
MsgBox "Please select filename in column 1"
Application.Run ("'Measurement Database SPA.xlsm'!Additional_Comments")

Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Workbooks("Parse_Compare_Import").Save
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End If
End Sub​
```

How do I display / show the workbook?

Answer (score 0):

I believe this should do what you want:

```
Option Explicit

' Needs to be at the top of the module
Public Declare Function SetForegroundWindow Lib "user32" (ByVal hWnd As Long) As Long

(...)

Sub test()
  Application.ScreenUpdating = True
  MSG1 = MsgBox("Would you like to add comments", vbYesNo, "Add comments")
  If MSG1 = vbYes Then

  Set y = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\Mohamed samatar.DSSE-EMEA\Documents\VBA Macros" _
          & "\Measurement Database Tool\Measurement Database SPA.xlsm")

  MsgBox "Please select filename in column 1"
  Application.Run ("'Measurement Database SPA.xlsm'!Additional_Comments")
  Workbooks("Measurement Database SPA").Activate
  SetForegroundWindow ActiveWorkbook.Application.hWnd
  (...)
End Sub
```

Comment: thanks for the response! what does this line actually do out of interest "Public Declare Function SetForegroundWindow Lib "user32" (ByVal hWnd As Long) As Long " ?...I will test this now and let you know the result!

Comment: You need to declare the function and tell where it is found because it is not a "native" VBA function, but rather a Windows-function. This pdf explains what happens pretty well: http://bit.ly/15NPliP. To quote its explanation of what the declaration of a similar function: "This statement tells the VBA interpreter that there is a function called GetSystemMetrics located in the file user32.exe (or user32.dll, it’ll check both) that takes one argument of a Long value and returns a Long value. Once defined, we can call GetSystemMetrics in exactly the same way as if it is the VBA function."

Comment: Hi It doesn't seem to be working I have been trying and it just asks if I want to add the comment, when I click yes it ends there? Any ideas

Comment: Hi to be more clear. It basically does not make the newly opened workbook visible.

Comment: Hmm. You could try using the BringWindowToTop-function instead, described briefly in point 4 [here](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/10-things/10-plus-of-my-favorite-windows-api-functions-to-use-in-office-applications/). Declare it as described there, then call it with `BringWindowToTop ActiveWorkbook.Application.hWnd`, after making the workbook you wish to make visible the active one.

Comment: Hi thanks for the support, it seems to be opening successfully and opening the userform successfully also however it is still running in the "background" and the active window is not displayed. Really odd! Is there a way of using a vba function to display the active window? I tried to previously use app.visible however that doesn't work so well either, as then it does not allow me to call the macro as it opens another excel application.

Comment: What if you make the function public, does that allow you to run it from the other application?

Comment: The closest I got to getting it to work was when I defined app as new Excel.Application , I then set y= app.workbooks.open...etc, I then set app.visible which successfully brings up to the front the newly opened workbook, the problem I get then is running the macro from this opened worksheet, from little research I have done it says you can not run a macro from another excel instance(excel application). So..you say make the function public however , Sorry, I am quite new to this, can you explain a little more what you mean by make it public,do you have any examples?

Comment: You add "Public" before declaring the function. `Public Function test() as Integer <function code> End Function` There's an example of a public function in the section "UDFs And Calculations" [here](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/writingfunctionsinvba.aspx).

Comment: Hi mate, completely stumped, can not seem to get my head around it, I have edited the code to my latest attempt, I have not had much luck with the Public Declare function mainly because I cant get it to work, please have a look at my edit and see if you can see any holes. I have realised the issue could be that the initial excel application is opened via MATLAB which is the reason it runs in the background, therefore any subsequemt excel workbooks are also not displayed.

Comment: Ah, I see the confusion. I meant that you made the function or sub you are trying to run public, not the declaration. Do what you almost got to work, but add "public" before the function or sub you tried to run, which should make it visible to other workbooks.